# Basic RNN training using fit_generator doesn't output the expected shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm implementing a basic RNN composed of a 512 units GRU and a dense layer using Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=512,
              return_sequences=True,
              input_shape=(None, num_x_signals,)))
model.add(Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I needed to generate input batches on the fly so I used `fit_generator` :

```
model.fit_generator(generator=generator_train, epochs=NB_EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                        validation_data=generator_test, validation_steps=900, callbacks=callbacks)
```

And here is how I define my batch generator :

```
SAMPLE_PERIOD_PER_INPUT = 1728
PERIOD_TO_PREDICT = 288
BATCH_SIZE = 64

def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length, train = True):
    while True:
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        y_shape = (batch_size, PERIOD_TO_PREDICT, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        for i in range(batch_size):
            if train:
                idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

                predict_idx = (idx + sequence_length) - PERIOD_TO_PREDICT

                x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
                y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[predict_idx:idx+sequence_length]
            else:
                idx = np.random.randint(num_test - sequence_length)

                predict_idx = (idx + sequence_length) - PERIOD_TO_PREDICT

                x_batch[i] = x_test_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
                y_batch[i] = y_test_scaled[predict_idx:idx+sequence_length]

        yield (x_batch, y_batch)

generator_train = batch_generator(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sequence_length=SAMPLE_PERIOD_PER_INPUT)
generator_test = batch_generator(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sequence_length=SAMPLE_PERIOD_PER_INPUT, train = False)
```

I also use a "custom" loss function because I need to ignore the first computed sequence which is supposed to not be accurate :

```
warmup_steps = 50

def loss_mse_warmup(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_slice = y_true[:, warmup_steps:, :]
    y_pred_slice = y_pred[:, warmup_steps:, :]

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true_slice,
                                        predictions=y_pred_slice)

    loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    return loss_mean

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Here is the summary of my model :

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
gru (GRU)                    (None, None, 512)         798720    
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, None, 1)           513       
=================================================================
Total params: 799,233
Trainable params: 799,233
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

But when I run this it says that there shape errors :

```
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [64,238,1] vs. [64,1678,1]
     [[{{node loss_4/dense_loss/mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]]
     [[loss_4/mul/_167]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [64,238,1] vs. [64,1678,1]
     [[{{node loss_4/dense_loss/mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Any ideas why ? Where did I write something wrong ?